# WebRTC call setup?

Tags: webrtc

I have been looking for the resource to understand webRTC call setup. As per my information which i have gathered from googling several resources. It includes a creation a peer connection, which in turn includes ice servers and then creating and sending a SDP offer for media negotiation.

I have tried few sample programs to understand it better. where i see a sdp offer and big list of ice candidates in logs.

But I am still not clear on how the flow starts and ends and what makes a successful connection?

Can anyone Explain it to me what are the steps include for a successful webRTC call OR point me to a better resource which explains everything in abstracted way.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The W3C documentation has a very good [diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#call-flow-browser-to-browser) which shows all the steps involve in a peer to peer connection.

Also in that page there are examples with code in [Section 11](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#examples-and-call-flows). It is a very dense page but very useful. Hope it helps!